# How to host multiple RRAS in same network?

Tags: windows-server-2003, rras

I have a Windows Server 2003 successfully hosting RRAS in my network (NATing with one public IP ).  Now I need to host another RRAS setup like the one I've got running, only with a different private IP address and public IP.

When I originally configured anew server to do this, both Windows 2003 servers froze and we lost internet connectivity.

So, how do I host 2 RRAS servers in the same network? (I am using RRAS to limit bandwidth for computers running private IPs through bandwith controller software, if it matters.)

Answer (score 1):

A network with multiple RRAS servers is certainly possible, and not all that uncommon, so I don't think your problem is anything inherent to having multiple RRAS servers.  Sounds more like the configuration on the new server created a routing loop or blocked access between your network and the rest of the 'net.  Unfortunately, I couldn't find a Server 2003 guide (really long past time to get ont0 Server 2008 R2), [but here's a guide for setting up RRAS on Server 2008/2008 R2 that you may find helpful](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff687863%28v=WS.10%29.aspx).

I'd recommend going over your network settings with a fine-toothed comb to see what's caused your problem.